# conditional ie css inclusion in Symfony 1.2

Tags: css, symfony1

I would like to load another css for IE. I'm using Symfony 1.2. What's the quickest way? I'd rather not use the "view.yml" technique. I'd like to have something like this in my head-section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
      <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<![endif]-->
```

I currently have this code in my layout.php file for including stylesheets.

```
<?php include_http_metas() ?>
<?php include_metas() ?>
<?php use_stylesheet('style.css') ?>
```

Do you guys know of any quick solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a problem with that. Just put this code into your layout.php

```
<?php include_http_metas() ?>
<?php include_metas() ?>
<?php use_stylesheet('style.css') ?>
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
  <?php echo stylesheet_tag('ie6'); ?>
<![endif]-->
```

Put ie6.css into stylesheets directory.

This way is much simplier since you don't have to hardcode path to your css directory.

Answer (score 6):

Symfony supports conditional CSS and JS, I don't see the reason not to use view.yml - it is enough to write in the view.yml (e.g. apps/frontend/config/view.yml)

CSS:

```
stylesheets:
 - ie6.css: { condition: IE 6 }
```

JS:

```
javascripts:
 - myiescript.js: { condition: IE 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the method [`addStylesheet`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWebResponse#method_addstylesheet) in the action.
Example:

```
$response->addStylesheet('ie8.css', '', array('condition' => 'IE 8'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has no support for conditional comments.

The easiest way it to put exactly that into your layout file, but instead of hardcoding the href attribute, use the `public_path` helper.

Comment: ? Sorry could you please give an example?

Comment: @Jojje you got another answer that pretty much does what I meant.